# Returning multiple PASS/FAIL

Tags: robotframework

If I have a list of strings `['PASS', 'FAIL', 'PASS']`, how can I return 
multiple PASS or FAIL status, depending on the string?  Right now I have something like:

```
test01
    :FOR  ${test}  IN @{tests}
    \    Log to Console  ${test}
    \    Should Match  ${test}  PASS
```

The robot framework will return:

```
test01
PASS
PASS
FAIL
test01                                                                | FAIL |
'FAIL' does not match 'PASS'
```

Essentially I want one test to dynamically generate the TEST_STATUS for an arbitrary length list, and the results to look something like:

```
test01
PASS                                                                  | PASS |
PASS                                                                  | PASS |
FAIL
test01                                                                | FAIL |
'FAIL' does not match 'PASS'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate test cases, since a test case has exactly one status, `PASS` or `FAIL`.

However, there are ways to ensure that all values in the list are handled. The easiest, I think, is using a test case template, like this

```
Test Case
    [Template]    Should Be Equal
    : FOR    ${status}    IN    @{VALUES}
    \    ${status}    PASS
```

With template, all the steps are run in continue on failure mode, which means that a failure does not prevent the loop from finishing. Instead, they failure(s) are collected and used to create a final status.

Comment: Yea, I already came to that conclusion, which is why i'm looking for a way to dynamically generate test cases.   Hopefully an option that doesn't involve generating a separate robot file.

Comment: Why do you want to have one test case with multiple status instead of many test cases? Also, with :FOR loops, you might be able to achieve something close to this.

Comment: To check the contents of an unknown list of arbitrary length.